# Error saving UIImage to CoreData entity as Binary Data

Tags: ios, iphone, core-data, swift, uiimage

When attempting to save a UIImage to a CoreData persistent store I am getting the following error:

***NSConcreteMutableData CGImage]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7fe85a4b5cd0
2014-12-28 20:27:16.307 MyAppName[1578:245578]  Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[NSConcreteMutableData CGImage]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7fe85a4b5cd0'***

The exception is thrown on `self.image = data` line of the `setImage(image: UIImage)` function.

Here is where I create the UIImage instance:

```
let ipaIcon = CoreData.newIconWithImageAndName(UIImage(named: "IPA-Day.png")!, name: "IPA-Day")
```

This function is in my data access layer:

```
class func newIconWithImageAndName(image:UIImage, name:String) -> Icon?
{
    if(Icon.ExistsInStorage(name))
    {
        return nil
    }
    var description = NSEntityDescription.entityForName(Lookup.EntityName.Icon.rawValue, inManagedObjectContext: context)

    var newIcon = Icon(entity: description!, insertIntoManagedObjectContext: context)

    newIcon.setImage(image)
    newIcon.name = name

    var saveError: NSError?

    context.save(&saveError)

    if let error = saveError
    {
        println("Error creating new icon with image and name: \(name)")
                return nil;
    }

    return newIcon

}
```

This is the code where I am saving the converting the image to NSData and attempting to set it to the NSData property of the managed object:

```
func setImage(image: UIImage)
{
    let data: NSData = UIImagePNGRepresentation(image)

    self.image = data
}
```

This is a screen shot of my xcdatamodel:
[image]

*** *I am running the latest release of Xcode(6.1) using Swift(1.1) .*

Comment: There is a conflict between your property name and your custom setter. That is what creating problem.

Comment: Please update your post with a code where you are setting the image.

Comment: I just have a suggestion, saving an even small image on the DB is not a really good idea. So if you do not have any specific reasons to do that I would rather save image paths and lazy instantiate images.Let's suppose that you fetch 100 icons you are loading in memory 100 NSData object, they could fill devices memory pretty soon.

Comment: @AdeelUrRehman, I have updated the post with the code you requested.

Comment: @Andrea, I will take your suggestion. I've read a bit about that and it seems reasonable. I leaned towards having the images in CoreData because the objects will come from a server, but even in that case I think I should still save the images to the file system. I am still interested in my question though. I saved the images the same way in Obj.-C and it worked fine, so I am curious as to why this isn't working. Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try doing this:

```
newIcon.image = UIImagePNGRepresentation(image)
```

Instead of this:

```
newIcon.setImage(image)
```

You define a setter for the property *image* explicitly but with a wrong parameter type. You have to do like this:

```
func setImage(data: NSData)
{
    image = data
}
```

and call it like this:

```
newIcon.setImage(UIImagePNGRepresentation(image))
```

Comment: The compiler was interpreting the setImage method to be a custom implementation of the auto-wired up setter (as I should have expected, btw) - and so, was calling itself. I got rid of the method setImage all together and just performed the setup with UIImagePNGRepresentation(image:) when setting the value. 

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You are facing this problem because you are trying to send the message CGImage to an NSData instance which of course does not have a CGImage method.

When you value attempts to transform the NSData instance while thinking it is UIImage, it generates the error.

Comment: I don't know how it becomes an instance of CGImage though. I instantiate it as a UIImage. The exception is thrown on `self.image = data` line of the `setImage(image: UIImage)` function. And I can verify the types in the lldb debugger.